# Rails - How to sort data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app that has a list of clients in one table (just a name attribute), and in another table, keeps track of their quarterly savings (amount, quarter, and year attributes). A `Client has_many :savings` and `Saving belongs_to :client`. As savings data gets entered, there is a spot to enter the quarter and the year (two separate fields), both integers. On the clients show page, I list the quarters that have savings data entered by doing the following:

In my clients_controller under show:

```
@savings = @client.savings
```

In my clients show.html.erb:

```
<% @savings.each do |saving| %>  
  <%= link_to "Q#{saving.quarter} #{saving.year}", edit_saving_path %>  
<% end %>
```

On the screen, this renders the quarter and date of the entries like "Q1 2011" and so on. However, it puts them in order of when they were entered, and I want them be in chronological order.

Two questions, how do I do order the entries, and second, is this the right way to list those savings entries for each client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1:

```
@savings = @client.savings.order("year")
```

2:
You should probably override to_s with this representation or at least put it in a helper as you'll probably need this representation "Q1 2011" more than once.

Bonus:
it should be edit_saving_path(saving)

Comment: Thanks, that totally made sense. For #2 I'm pretty new at this, what do you mean override to_s (I don't see that in the code, must be a default?) with this representation or put it in a helper? Which part? And what does putting (saving) at the end of the path do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fattryan..he meant to say you can add a method in model `Saving` like this `def to_s; "Q#{quarter}#{year}"; end` so that you can call `link_to saving.to_s, edit_saving_path(saving)` in the view.